# Skype Web API sign in issues using login and password

Tags: sdk, skype

I have issue with signing into Skype account using login and password. I use code from Skype Web SDK docs:

```
<script>
// Call the application object
var config = {
apiKey: 'a42fcebd-5b43-4b89-a065-74450fb91255', // SDK
apiKeyCC: '9c967f6b-a846-4df2-b43d-5167e47d81e1' // SDK+UI
};

var Application;

Skype.initialize({ apiKey: config.apiKey }, function (api) {
    window.skypeWebApp = new api.application();

    window.skypeWebApp.signInManager.signIn({
       username: "test@yandex.ru",
       password: "12345678"
    }).then(function () {
       console.log('Signed in successfully.');
    }, function (error) {
       console.log('Failed to sign in.');
    }).then(reset);
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    alert('Cannot load the SDK.');
});
</script>
```

The POST request is sent, but API returns nothing. Can anybody advise?